# mysql - UNION items with parameters not included in previously SELECTed items

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a selection of items from two tables - `table1`, `table2`:

```
table1
id (primary) | user_id | group_id | name | description | active_from | active_to
```

and

```
table2
id (primary) | user_id | group_id | name | description | active_from
```

Each item from those tables belongs to certain group. The code I already have for showing the items is the following:

```
SELECT 'table1' AS table_name, id, user_id, group_id, name, description, active_from, active_to
FROM table1 WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' AS table_name, id, user_id, group_id, name, description, active_from, null
FROM table2 WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'
ORDER BY group_id, name ASC
```

The code above gives me the list of items from `table1` and `table2` grouped by group_id (and then by name). The list of groups is contained in table `groups`. Structure of the table `groups`:

```
group_id (primary) | user_id | group_name
```

However, there are some groups that contain no items from `table1` or `table2`. What I try to add to the current result are also those empty groups (to be listed in the same way as items) and to sort the result based on the group_name.

I tried to use the following code, which throws "You have an error in your SQL syntax":

```
(SELECT 'table1' AS table_name, id, user_id, group_id, name, description, active_from, active_to
FROM table1 WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' AS table_name, id, user_id, group_id, name, description, active_from, null
FROM table2 WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'
ORDER BY group_id, name ASC) as items_all
UNION ALL
SELECT 'groups_empty' as table_name, null, null, group_id, null, null, null, null 
FROM groups WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' AND group_id!=items_all.group_id
```

1. How can I add the empty groups to the list of items (just to show the group_id and empty row)?
2. How to show group_name instead of group_id (and order the result by group_name rather than group_id)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use proper parentheses separating the `union all` for better visibility. Now the condition at the last union all is not correct and you may either need `left join` or `not exists` something as

```
(
  SELECT 
  'table1' AS table_name, 
  id, 
  user_id, 
  group_id, 
  name, 
  description, 
  active_from, 
  active_to
  FROM table1 
  WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'
)
 UNION ALL
(  
  SELECT 
  'table2' AS table_name, 
  id, 
  user_id, 
  group_id, 
  name, 
  description, 
  active_from, 
  null
  FROM table2 
  WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'
  ORDER BY group_id, name ASC
) 
 UNION ALL
(
  SELECT 
  'groups_empty' as table_name, 
  null, 
  null, 
  group_id, 
  null, 
  null, 
  null, 
  null 
  FROM groups 
  WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' 
  AND
  not exists(
    select 1 from table2 where table2.group_id = groups.group_id
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Your solution is working and solving my question no. 1. Do you have some idea about question no. 2 - sorting the result according to the group names? For saving time, I created sql fiddle at  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a899e/3

Comment: Actually no. Currently, the results are ordered based on group_id. What I try is to list the results based on group_name (stated in the table groups). Some hint?

Comment: Could you explain a bit, may be in to the question using the current result set as example and expected result set from that ?

Comment: Sure. It is simple - just in the fourth column of results (currently group_id), show name of the groups (group_name). For example: for the first result, instead of group_id 1 to show 'Small group'; for the second result the same; for the third result, instead of the group_id 2 to show 'Medium group' etc.

Comment: Cool, that is exactly it.